# How to use offset(margin) with display grid

Tags: css, frontend, web-frontend

Well, it is time to use the new layout method with `display: grid` in CSS.
I tried to use grid in my CSS lib, and for compatibility with old browsers, I will keep the same API and same appearance. But I'm facing a problem of how to use offset in `display:grid` like bootstrap.css, margin not working.

Pug(Jade)

```
.row.gutter
  .col.col-6
  .col.col-6  
  .col.col-6  
  .col.col-6  
  .col.col-6  
  .col.col-5.offset-1  
  .col.col-4.offset-2
```

stylus

```
*
  box-sizing:border-box
.row
  display:grid
  grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr)
  grid-gap 10px
 .col
   background:red
   height 100px 
 for $item in 1..25
   .col-{$item}
     grid-column-end span $item
   //how to do for offset property
   // .offset-{$item}
         margin-left percentage($item / 24)
```

Thanks for your help

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/carlosJoo/pen/RwrJzWx)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this may be it help you.

```css
.col.col-6.offset-2
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
```